# How to position OccupancyGrid in RVis - understanding TF

Tags: ros2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I've just started with ROS and I need help understanding how TF works.

I'm trying to run this simulation on ROS2 Eloquent:
https://github.com/chapulina/dolly
and I'd like to use SLAM from Slam Toolbox:
https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox

The robot has 2 frames:
https://github.com/chapulina/dolly/blob/master/dolly_gazebo/models/dolly/model.sdf#L348-L353.

```
  <!-- output -->
  <publish_odom>true</publish_odom>
  <publish_odom_tf>true</publish_odom_tf>
 
  <odometry_frame>odom_demo</odometry_frame>
  <robot_base_frame>chassis</robot_base_frame>
```

The robot is positioned at -37 5.6 in the "world":
https://github.com/chapulina/dolly/blob/master/dolly_gazebo/worlds/dolly_city.world#L4480

```
<!-- Dolly -->
<include>
  <pose>-37 5.6 0.33 0 0 0</pose>
  <uri>model://dolly</uri>
</include>
```

When I run `slam_toolbox` it outputs `/map` topic with `OccupancyGrid` messages.
I'm using `static_transform_publisher` to transform `map` frame to `chassis` with all zeroes.

Now in RViz I see all 3 frames in the center of the grid (`map`, `chassis` and `odom_demo`).
I can also see the laser scan results which start from the center of the grid.

However I see the map display way outside of the grid.
I suspect it's because robot position is at -37 5.6, `chassis` and `map` are statically linked through `static_transform_publisher`,
which "pushes" map away from center.  Here is how it looks(don't have enough point to post an image directly):
https://imgur.com/a/xFMjuOj

What I'd like to see is map being in the center and see robot move on the grid as I move the robot in simulation.
Something like the last gif on https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox

Am I correct in assuming that I need:

1. Make `map` a "fixed frame" in Rviz
2. Somehow make transformation between `map` and `odom_demo` dynamic so it would take position calculated via slam_toolbox
   and transform it to the robot position on the grid.

This way "OccupancyGrid" will stay at the center of RViz grid and when robot moves it will change `odom_demo` position which will change `chassis` frame with it.
How do I do that? Does slam_toolbox already have this transformation?
Is this even a correct understanding of what TF means?

Another question:
I've been reading https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html and I think my frames correspond to:
`earth` -> don't have one, I've also seen `world` in a couple of places, how do I create one?
`map` -> `map`
`odom` -> `odom_demo`
`chassis` -> `base_link`

Is this correct?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343969/how-to-position-occupancygrid-in-rvis---understanding-tf/) by [Leonti](https://answers.ros.org/users/51710/leonti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2020-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like my initial understanding was correct - chassis -> map transforms were already published by Slam Toolbox, I just had to select `map` as a Fixed Frame in Rviz.

The second problem was not using the sim time in Slam Toolbox, so the map was published with the system's timestamp, so the transform only worked in one direction (I could select `odom_demo` as a fixed frame in RViz, but not the `map`).
Switching to sim time and checking `Use Timestamp` in RViz for the `Map` solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Leonti](https://answers.ros.org/users/51710/leonti/) with karma: 62 on 2020-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0